# Visit Cuba on an Indian passport with valid UK Visa

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, cuba

I found a few online links like this one which states that Indian citizens can visit Cuba with a Tourist card and a valid UK Visa.

https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/

Is this true for Indian Passport holders ?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the link to Timatic given in that article and fill in the form, including Cuba as the destination, you'll get this:

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Nationals of India with
> a visa issued by Canada, USA or an EU Member state . They must also
> hold a Tourist Card (Tarjeta del Turista) issued to visitors traveling
> as tourists.
>
> Nationals of India with a work or student permit issued by Canada, USA
> or an EU Member state . They must also hold a Tourist Card (Tarjeta
> del Turista) issued to visitors traveling as tourists.

Note that the UK will (possibly) leave the EU on 29 March 2019 so this might no longer apply for UK visas after that date.