# Cuba visa for Indian Passport

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, cuba

If Indian Passport holder doesn't have USA or Canada visa or EU visa, Can he/she enter Cuba?

What is Tourist Card ? Is Tourist Card require for all traveller even if they hold USA or CAN ?

Please assist.

Comment: This q & A are closely related, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123897/visit-cuba-on-an-indian-passport-with-valid-uk-visa?rq=1

Comment: Also worth mentioning that travelling to Cuba will  jeopardise your future entry into the US

Comment: A paper ‘tourist card’ used to be issued by airlines/travel operators but is now available online and is similar in concept to an eTA/ESTA http://visasonline.cubaminrex.cu/en

Answer (score 5):

You will need a visa in order to travel to Cuba.

The [webpage of the Embassy of Cuba in New Delhi](https://www.embassypages.com/cuba-embassy-newdelhi-india) says:

> **VISA REGULATIONS FOR CUBA**
>
> Indian citizens require a visa and a valid passport to enter Cuba. The embassy of Cuba in New Delhi may be able to process visa applications. Contact the embassy directly to inquire about the availability of a visa from the embassy.

Nothing is mentioned about waiving the requirment to obtain a Cuban visa if you have a US, Canada, or EU visa. Ask the consular staff at the Cuban Embassy.

The [Wikipedia page "Visa Policy of Cuba"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Cuba#Tourist_card_required) says (citing TIMATIC) that citizens of India are ineligible to obtain a tourist card, and must instead obtain a visa.

Comment: Also don’t forget you may need a visa for some transit countries on your way there.